# Sync files timestamp with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm capturing video from 4 cameras connected with HDMI through a capture card. I'm using ffmpeg to save the video feed from the cameras to multiples jpeg files (30 jpeg per second per camera).

I want to be able to save the images with the capture time. Currently I'm using this command for one camera:

ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -pixel_format yuv420p -timestamps abs -I /dev/video0 -c:a jpeg -t 60 -ts_from_file 2 camera0-%5d.jpeg

It saves my file with the names camera0-00001.jpg, camera0-00002.jpg, etc.

Then I rename my file with camera0-HH-mm-ss-(1-30).jpeg based on the modified time of the file.

So in the end I have 4 files with the same time and same frame like this:
camera0-12-00-00-1.jpeg
camera1-12-00-00-1.jpeg
camera2-12-00-00-1.jpeg
camera3-12-00-00-1.jpeg

My issue is that the file may be offset from one to two frame. They may have the same name but sometime one or two camera may show different frame.

Is there a way to be sure that the capture frames has the actual time of the capture and not the time of the creation of the file?

Comment: Why the fps filter?

Comment: It was useless, I removed it, but it still doesn't fix my sync issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the mkvtimestamp_v2 muxer

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -pixel_format yuv420p -timestamps abs -copyts -i /dev/video0 \
       -vf setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -vsync 0 -vframes 1800 camera0-%5d.jpeg \
       -c copy -vsync 0 -vframes 1800 -f mkvtimestamp_v2 timings.txt
```

timings.txt will have output like this

```
# timecode format v2
1521177189530
1521177189630
1521177189700
1521177189770
1521177189820
1521177189870
1521177189920
1521177189970
...
```

where each reading is the Unix epoch time in milliseconds.

I've switched to output frame count limit to stop the process instead of `-t 60`. You can use `-t 60` for the first output since we are resetting timestamps there, but not for the second. If you do that, remember to only use the first N entries from the text file, where N is the number of images produced.

Comment: I tried your solution but I have an issue. My capture cards has issue with Linux so I have to make it work with Windows and dshow. My timestamp is not absolute with dshow and my timestamp are only the the value of capture. Ex: 0, 33, 66, 100, etc

Comment: Add `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -copyts` before `-i`

Comment: It working with those parameters on Windows thanks! Is it normal that the timings.txt is empty until the video is done recording? Because I would like to start syncing file while ffmpeg is recording.

Comment: Try adding `-flush_packets 1` before the text filename. When writing to disk, ffmpeg will wait till 256kB of buffer is in queue before it writes.

Comment: I have an issue when I check at the timestamp from 4 inputs, it seems that they are not correctly sync, they sometime get 1 or two frame offset. Also when I look at the ffmpeg log, the fps is not fixed to 30 it's always changing between 25 and 30 even with the -framerate 30 and -r 30 parameters.

Comment: Here is my command:
 `ffmpeg -vsync 0 -f dshow -rtbufsize 1500M -video_size 1920x1080 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -copyts -r 30 -i video="QP0203 PCI, Analog 01 Capture" -r 30 -vf setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -vsync 0 -vframes 300 camera1/%d.jpeg -c copy -vsync 0 -vframes 300 -f mkvtimestamp_v2 timings1.txt` My issue is when I start more than 4 capture on the same computer. I see some of my ffmpeg commands running at 28 fps or less.

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old thread. On windows, I get `Unrecognized option 'timestamps'.`. I have replaced timestamps with `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -copyts ` but the timestamp output seems to be milliseconds since startup. How can I get an absolute timestamp (e.g. Epoch time?)