# can i use windows api function on ffmpeg code?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying recording video from camera and receive timestamp when frame received.
I want to extracting timestamp each frame on Windows.
And I'm trying use this ffmpeg commandline.
[Sync files timestamp with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287744/sync-files-timestamp-with-ffmpeg/49313678#49313678)

ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 1500M -video_size 1920x1080 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -copyts -r 60 -i video="0819-INOGENI 4K2USB3" -r 60 -vf setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -q 4 video4567.avi -c copy -f mkvtimestamp_v2 timings4567.txt

but I want to timestamp based on GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime  function, not unix epoch time for much better sensitive timer.

So, I'm trying modifying to use GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime function mkvtimestamp_v2 code.
But it's error when make install processing.
like this : libavformat.a(mkvtimestamp_v2.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime referenced in function _write_packet

It seems like no link win32 api from ffmpeg code.

Is there any way for linking win32 api for ffmpeg code?

thanks :)